# Octave: Filling specific values in random cells inside a table

Tags: random, octave

I am trying to fill some values in a table (1 row n columns). 1 and 0 must be inside the table but in random positions and the remaining cells have to be random values between 0 and 1.

e.g for n=4 P should look something like this

P = 0.0000   0.58177  1.00000   0.86008

What I have done is: filling the first two positions inside the table with 1 and 0 and the rest of n (if n>2) is filled with randomized values [0,1]. Any ideas how to fix my code are welcome.

```
function P=pairwise_matrix(n)

P=zeros(1,n);

 a = 0; b = 1;
 x = a + (b-a) .* rand(1,1);



  P(1,1)=1

  if (n==1)
    printf("not applicable")
  endif

  if (n==2)
    P(1,1)=0
    P(1,2)=1
  endif


  for (i=3:n)
        P(1,i)=rand(x);
  endfor




endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fill the vector with random values, than define 
two random positions for `0` and `1`

```
function P=pairwise_matrix(n)

if (n<3) n=3; endif

P=rand(1,n); # fill vector with random numbers

n0=floor(n*rand()); # random integer between 0 and n-1
n1=mod(n0+1+floor((n-1)*rand()),n); # random integer different from n0

P(n0+1)=0;
P(n1+1)=1;

endfunction
```

so we have

```
octave:65> pairwise_matrix(3)
ans =

   1.00000   0.73595   0.00000

octave:66> pairwise_matrix(7)
ans =

   0.19995   0.01847   1.00000   0.31813   0.84074   0.00000   0.68086
```